# Working with Angular and Node best practices

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mean-stack

I am in the process of learning the MEAN stack, or PEAN stack (Postgres).  There are a lot of helpful tutorials online to get started but something still isn't clicking for me.

From what I have gathered there are multiple ways to approach this.  I see tutorials that start a Node project, add Express, Angular etc in something like a client folder or whatever naming convention.  Then there are other tutorials that begin with an Angular project

```
ng new client
```

and then add some other modules that way.

Where I am at now is I have a Node project using Express to build a rest API which is fine and working as intended.  Then I also have a client folder where I initialized an Angular project via

```
ng new client.
```

What is odd to me is the need to start both servers (different ports) for the project.

Is this normal practice to approach the project like this?  Or is it preferable to include Angular within the node project and use Express sendFile to render the html files?  I am currently trying to use:

```
app.sendFile('app.component.html')
```

in Express and reference the app.component.html file in my Angular project.  This will render the button but does not apply any styling that should be applied from within the Angular project.

If I run:

```
ng serve
```

on the Angular project from within the client folder, the same html page gets rendered properly with styling included.

Is it better to keep the client and the api separated thus forcing me to run something like (for development purposes)...

```
nodemon
```

To start the web server and accept requests... Then also run..

```
ng serve
```

To start the client and begin making calls?

This is my first post so I hope it's not too subjective.  There isn't much information that I have found which covers this type of question in regards to the stack.  Most of the tutorials are simply code based and not theoretical.  Any help or advice on the subject would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It IS a subjective question so I can only give my point of view: it is better to dissociate your client from your server. That way, you're sure to know which part goes where ;)
Plus, you will probably use two quite different stacks for back- and front-end (Express vs Angular). Keeping two separated projects will keep your dependencies separated, etc... And if at some point you want to change your stack for either client or server, then you can without changing the stack for the whole thing or struggling to know which part is client which part is server.

I'm currently working on a project where client and server are all in one place. I definitely don't recommend it to anyone... Especially for a web project.

That said, I'd advise to have the same naming/indentation/... conventions in both projects (as they are in the same language). That would allow people to easily work on both. Angular has [some guidelines about how to write great code](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide).

It is not odd at all (at least to me) to have the server separated, because that way you can work on the server only, without consuming resources for an unused client. Also, you can design your client with Lorem ipsum so that you initially don't need to launch the server to work on it ;)

Side note: `ng serve` is supposed to be used for development purposes only. Don't use it for production. To deploy your client: `ng build --prod`. This will compile your client and put it in the folder specified by your compilation configuration (/dist is the default).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Glad to know that I am on the right path then minus the fact that I was trying to use Express to render my angular pages.  Seems like instead I just need to use Angular to fetch the results from the REST api.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the app.sendFile('app.component.html') solution.  The only advantage of using the ng server is that while you are developing the Angular side, ng server will automatically pick-up the changes.  But you can use ng build --watch to do that.  I personally haven't used nodemon yet, but it sounds like a reasonable solultion.
The problem with doing ng server  and node is that you need to use CORS in order for it all to work -- the Angular server will be using a different port, and therefore will be a different website so to speak.  I did that for a while.

It would look something like this

```
    const cors = require('cors')
    var corsOptions = {
       origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
       optionsSuccessStatus: 

     }
    app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

EDIT:

Since posting this answer, I've found another solution that works for me.
Running ng serve using a proxy.   It looks like this for me.
  ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json

The config file looks like this

```
{
"/machine/*":{
      "target":"http://X.y.com:8080",
      "secure":false,
  "logLevel":"debug"
},
"/lookup/*":{
    "target":"http://X.y.com:8080",
    "secure":false,
    "logLevel":"debug"
  },
  "/edit/*":{
    "target":"http://x.y.com:8080",
    "secure":false,
    "logLevel":"debug"
  },
  "/delete/*":{
    "target":"http://x.y.com:8080",
    "secure":false,
    "logLevel":"debug"
  },
  "/edit/*":{
    "target":"http://x.y.com:8080",
    "secure":false,
    "logLevel":"debug"
  },
  "/list/*":{
    "target":"http://x.y.com:8080",
    "secure":false,
    "logLevel":"debug"
}
```

The express app actually runs on another machine.  You can share the backend with the full express app that is running on that machine - you are only running the part that accesses data -  a  RESTFul interface for instance.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response!  So is it safe to assume that if app.sendFile('app.component.html') is rendering the button on that page, but not any of the styling that something is probably just wrong with my code somewhere, but not necessarily my approach?

Comment: I agree with @Moi.  It's better to keep the actual projects separate. But you can serve the Angular index page by  doing the sendFile() ..  All it does is send that html page back to the client.  In my particular case, my calls back to node are for data only.
All my node routes send json back to the client